# aws-cdk: specify default API Gateway responses

Tags: aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

I'd like to modify [the default BAD_REQUEST_BODY template](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-gatewayResponse-definition.html) to return validation errors:

```
{ 
  "message":$context.error.messageString, 
  "validationErrors":"$context.error.validationErrorString" 
}
```

Is there a way to do this now?